# How to change focus color of EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

How can I change the focus color (orange) on an `EditText` box?

The focus color is a small rim around the entire control and is bright
orange when the control has focus.  How can I change the color of that
focus to a different color?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You'll have to create/modify your own NinePatch image to replace the default one, and use that as the background of your EditText. If you look in your SDK folder, under your platform, then res/drawable, you should find the NinePatch image for the EditText focus state. If that's all you want to change, you can just pull it into Photoshop, or whatever image editing software you have, and change the orange color to a color of your choosing. Then save that into your drawable folder, and build a new StateListDrawable, for example something like the below:

**edittext_modified_states.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/edittext_pressed" 
        /> <!-- pressed -->    
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_focused_blue" 
        /> <!-- focused -->    
    <item 
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/edittext_normal" 
        /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

I don't know offhand the actual names for the default NinePatches for the EditText, so replace those as necessary, but the key here is to just use the `@android:drawable` images for the ones you haven't modified (or you can copy them over to your project's drawable folder), and then use your modified drawable for your focused state.

You can then set this StateListDrawable as the background for your TextView, like so:

```
<TextView
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_modified_states"
```

Comment: On which Android version does this solution work? I've tried to change the color in Android 2.1, but it seems that the names and xml files are different in it. I understand the idea, but frustration is growing as I face tons of errors all the time.

Comment: In 2.1 I had to copy also the normal unmodified state pictures into the applications drawable folder to get this work. So in my applications drawable folder I have the modified focus state picture and also unmodified original other state pictures as well. Now it works.

Comment: It might not work, like I said you may have to copy them to your folder (as it looks like you did); this was just a solution from the top of my head. :)

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to create xml drawables. It may be more simple in code.
Example in kotlin:

```
editText.onFocusChangeListener = OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    // colorLine, colorLineFocus is vars of ColorStateList
    ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(editText, if (hasFocus) colorLineFocus else colorLine)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
    <item 
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="colorcode" 
    /> <!-- pressed -->    
    <item 
       android:state_focused="true"
       android:color="colorcode"
    /> <!-- focused -->    
    <item 
           android:color="colorcode"
    /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: this code is not working showing me this error "02-07 03:45:01.131: E/AndroidRuntime(2911): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #8: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
"

Comment: try `<item drawable="@color/colorcode">` instead of `android:color`

Comment: @andrewww create color.xml in `res/color` folder and try `android:color="@color/colorname"`