# how to change default orange color when press button any one tell me

Tags: android

how to change the default color orange  when tyoping text in edittext field or press button  how that color will change? any help?? this is my xml below when i run this code  default orange color is appear on border of edittext and    when pressing button

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:background="#ffffff">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtEnterPinForTransaction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblPinno"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtPinno"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnsubmit"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clearButton"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Clear" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btngoback"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go Back" />
```

Comment: set any color of edittext by android:background="@android:color/white"

Comment: refer this previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882064/how-to-change-color-of-button-in-android-when-clicked

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which component's color you want to change and when?

Comment: refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584882/how-to-change-focus-color-of-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You can create an stateListdrawable which defines, different colors or drawables for different states of Button, and can set this xml drawable as background of the button.

For example for the button you can use following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

save this xml into Res-> drawable folder with btn_selector.xml, now set this to background of the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnsubmit"
    android:background="@+drawable/btn_selector"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit" />
```

If still something unclear, refer

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: sorry its not clear tell my by example how to change the default orange color of button or edittext field

Comment: what is the resources od button_pressed    button_focused  is color or pictures??

Comment: It might be any system resource or some other image, try by paste some png image with names button_focused, button_pressed, button_normal into drawable, you will got

Comment: what is @@drawable/button_pressed
@drawable/button_focused"