# how to change the edit text color on focusing in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I don't know how to change the back ground color of edit text in android,at the time of focus and pressing?

Comment: possible duplicated: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584882/how-to-change-focus-color-of-edittext-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584882/how-to-change-focus-color-of-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

use selector xml tag to do this.

Comment: provide me a good example for this.I already using a list selector tag undeer this xml.Can i also use selector tag in same xml file?

Answer (score 0):

**edit_text_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_focus"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edit_text_border" />
</selector>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/edit_text_selector"
android:hint="@string/password" />
```