# how to change color of TextinputLayout's label and edittext underline android

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

I am using android design library's `TextinputLayout`. But couldn't customize the hint color, label color and the underline color of `EditText` inside `TextinputLayout`. Please help.

Comment: It should have the accent color according to design guidelines right?

Comment: ya, but I will have many editTexts with colors different from theme's accent color.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EditText underline below text property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480398/edittext-underline-below-text-property)

Comment: I could change underline reliably in both focused and unfocused state by using custom background drawable specified in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36543554/2413303

Answer (score 278, accepted):

### Change bottom line color:

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7)

> ```
>  <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
>  <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
>  <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent</item>
> ```

### Change hint color when it is floating

```
<style name="MyHintStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_color</item>
</style>
```

and use it like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyHintStyle">
```

### Change hint color when it is not a floating label:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyHintStyle"
    android:textColorHint="#c1c2c4">
```

*Thanks to [@AlbAtNf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722034/how-to-change-color-of-textinputlayouts-label-and-edittext-underline-android?lq=1#comment59806051_31723120)*

Comment: I am not able to change hint color (when its not label).Could you help?

Comment: I am really concerned about my app size , considering that, any idea on how much addition size is it expected to put on my app?

Comment: sorry, didn't get your question, please explain more, size in what context, graphics size of app weight (Like apk is of above 20mb or something), and earlier you accept my answer and again you remove your acceptance,can i ask, y so?

Comment: becoz , I couldn't change hint color following your answer. Some part of it worked for me but this is not complete solution to what I asked.Regarding app size, doesn't adding external library like Material EdiTText increase app size?

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for this for a few hours!

Comment: @NiteshVerma found the solution for setting Hint Color, when it is not a floating lable: simply set `android:textColorHint` to `TextInputLayout` in XML.

Comment: Tried many ways. This is the perfect way described in this answer

Comment: I was able to change the bottom color but when I select the box, it becames the same color of the AccentColor, and not from `<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/Black</item>`

Comment: `app:hintTextAppearance` is completly ignored in my case in favor of `android:textColorHint`

Comment: I don't think this worked for me as I tried many, I had to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758958/change-thickness-of-the-bottom-line-of-edittext-when-wrapped-into-textinputlayou/36543554#36543554

Comment: Not working for me :( I can't believe there's no simple way to do this.....

Comment: For TextInputLayoutTheme in style file: Use this Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox Because this will work perfectly in case of androidx.

Comment: colorControlActivated will override the hint color

Answer (score 45):

With the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can use the [**`com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md).

You can apply a custom style to change the colors.

**To change the hint color** you have to use these attributes:
 **`hintTextColor`** and **`android:textColorHint`**.

```
<style name="Custom_textinputlayout_filledbox" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <!-- The color of the label when it is collapsed and the text field is active -->
    <item name="hintTextColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>

    <!-- The color of the label in all other text field states (such as resting and disabled) -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/selector_hint_text_color</item>
</style>
```

You should use a selector for the `android:textColorHint`. Something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

**To change the bottom line color** you have to use the attribute: **`boxStrokeColor`**.

```
<style name="Custom_textinputlayout_filledbox" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    ....
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/selector_stroke_color</item>
</style>
```

Also in this case you should use a selector. Something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

[image] [image]

You can also apply these attributes in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/selector_stroke_color"
    app:hintTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:textColorHint="@color/selector_hint_text_color"
    ...>
```

Comment: How to change the underline color of EditText inside TextinputLayout? I mean unfocused state. It's grayish

Comment: @EvgeniiVorobei It is described in the answer. It is defined by the `boxStrokeColor`. In the example the `selector_stroke_color` in particular the last line: `<item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>`

Comment: Thank you soooo much! I couldn't figure it out by myself.

Comment: my problem is i want the hint color to be gray and once the edittext is filled i want it to be orange no matter if its focused or not. i am able to do it when its focused. but not able to do it when it is not. So chan you help me with it @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: This is the only solution worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 35):

Based on [Fedor Kazakov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31722303/2826279) and others answers, I created a default config.

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance</item>
        <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextErrorAppearance</item>
        <item name="counterTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Counter</item>
        <item name="counterOverflowTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Counter.Overflow</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
        <!-- Floating label appearance here -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextErrorAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
        <!-- Error message appearance here -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

activity_layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Text hint here"
        android:text="5,2" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

---

Focused:

[image: Focused]

Without focus:

[image: Without focus]

Error message:

[image]

Comment: What should I do in order to also get pink color for "Without focus" example?

Comment: how to use this style?

Answer (score 28):

Add this attribute in Edittext tag and enjoy:

```
 android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
```

Comment: effect: changes the line color on devices with API level 21 and above

Comment: It is working as expected +1 for this answer

Answer (score 18):

This [Blog Post](http://blog.specktre.com/blog/2015/11/23/android-styling-textinputlayout/) describes various styling aspects of `EditText` and `AutoCompleteTextView` wrapped by `TextInputLayout`.

For `EditText` and *AppCompat lib 22.1.0+* you can set theme attribute with some theme related settings:

```xml
<style name="StyledTilEditTextTheme">
   <item name="android:imeOptions">actionNext</item>
   <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/greyLight</item>
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/styledtil_edit_text_size</item>
</style>

<style name="StyledTilEditText">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/StyledTilEditTextTheme</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">4dp</item>
</style>
```

and apply them on `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etEditText"
    style="@style/StyledTilEditText"
```

For `AutoCompleteTextView` things are more complicated because wrapping it in `TextInputLayout` and applying this theme breaks floating label behaviour. 
You need to fix this in code:

```java
private void setStyleForTextForAutoComplete(int color) {
    Drawable wrappedDrawable =     DrawableCompat.wrap(autoCompleteTextView.getBackground());
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, color);
    autoCompleteTextView.setBackgroundDrawable(wrappedDrawable);
}
```

and in `Activity.onCreate`:

```java
setStyleForTextForAutoComplete(getResources().getColor(R.color.greyLight));
autoCompleteTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
    if(hasFocus) {
        setStyleForTextForAutoComplete(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    } else {
        if(autoCompleteTextView.getText().length() == 0) {  
              setStyleForTextForAutoComplete(getResources().getColor(R.color.greyLight));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to change the **bar/line color and the hint text color** of the `TextInputLayout` (what the accent color normally is), then just create this style:

```
<style name="MyStyle">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

Then apply it to your `TextInputLayout` as a *theme*:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:theme="@style/MyStyle" />
```

This basically sets a *theme* (not style) to one view (as opposed to the whole activity).

Comment: Your Min SDK should be 21

Answer (score 10):

A `TextinputLayout` is not a view, but a `Layout`, as very nicely described by [Dimitrios Tsigouris](https://medium.com/@Dimitris_CBR) in [his blog post here](https://medium.com/fw-engineering/textinputlayout-proper-theming-dde422e86c43). Therefore, you don't need a `Style`, which is for `Views` only, but use a `Theme`. Following the blog post, I ended up with the following solution:

**Start in your `styles.xml` with**

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutAppearance" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
        <!-- reference our hint & error styles -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_colour_here</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/your_colour_here</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/your_colour_here</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your_colour_here</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/your_colour_here</item>
</style>
```

**And in your layout add**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance"
...
```

Comment: Use Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox in parent

Comment: android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance" this doesn't render view in xml layout in android studio but works perfectly fine in mobile

Answer (score 6):

```
<style name="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Hint</item>
    <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Error</item>
</style>
```

You can override this style for layout

And also you can change inner EditText-item style too.

Comment: how to use this style ?
is there any way to override all app's style at one place?

Answer (score 6):

```
<style name="EditScreenTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/actionBar_background</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/actionBar_background</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/actionBar_background</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/actionBar_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/actionBar_background</item>
</style>
```

apply this style to TextInputLayout

Comment: just a quick note for applying the style to TextInputLayout: `android:theme="@style/EditScreenTextInputLayoutStyle"`

Answer (score 4):

I used all of the above answers and none worked. This answer works for **API 21+**. Use **app:hintTextColor** attribute when text field is focused and **app:textColorHint** attribute when in other states. To change the bottmline color use this attribute **app:boxStrokeColor** as demonstrated below:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
    
       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

It works for **AutoCompleteTextView** as well. Hope it works for you:)

Answer (score 4):

Change line color of TextInputLayout + TextInputEditText

### colors.xml

```
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true">@color/lineColor</color>
```

### styles.xml

```
<style name="TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/lineColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hintColor</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/backgroundColor</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputEditText" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

### layout.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/TextInputEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Works for me. If you trying EditText with Label and trying change to underline color use this. Change to TextInputEditText instead EditText.

```
           <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    android:hint="Lastname"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the **label color** of `TextInputLayout` by using `app:hintTextAppearance` attribute in `TextInputLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Style**:

```
 <style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" 
 parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>
```

To change `edittext` underline color, you can use `android:backgroundTint`

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Underline color change"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Create style as mentioned below

```
<style name="text_input_layout_style">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

and apply it to your `TextInputLayout` as `android:theme="@style/text_input_layout_style"`

And definitely will work for you all.

Comment: No solution worked for me because my app theme is Appcompat based, not Material one, this one helped me... Thanks, dude...

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the bottom line color of a TextInputEditText inside a TextInputLayout and then the other answers didn't work out. I finally solved it by setting the colorOnSurface for the TextInputLayouts theme. I'll leave my code here in case it helps someone else.

XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme=""@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.te`tfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Style:

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutStyle">
    <item name="colorOnSurface">#0ff</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_profile_textInputLayout_mobile"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="Mobile Number"
        app:theme="@style/EditBoxColor">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/activity_profile_textInputEditText_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Style

```
<style name="EditBoxColor" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPurple</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPurple3</item>
</style>
```