# Style TextInputLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-textinputlayout

Is there a way to customize these [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) properties programmatically:

- textColorHint
- colorAccent
- colorControlNormal
- colorControlActivated
- textSelectHandle

I know how to style them using theme attributes, but the project I'm working on loads color information dynamically, and as far as I understand there is no way of changing theme/style values at runtime.

Comment: You may find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722034/how-to-change-color-of-textinputlayouts-label-and-edittext-underline-android/31723120#31723120

Comment: The question was to set it programatically.

Answer (score 4):

I write textInputLayout implemention, that can set any color of underline and error and show error on top.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
public class TextInputLayoutUseful extends TextInputLayout {
private CharSequence originalHint = "";

public TextInputLayoutUseful(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public TextInputLayoutUseful(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public TextInputLayoutUseful(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    this.originalHint = getHint();
    setErrorEnabled(false);
}

/**
 * - put error text into top floating label
 * - colorized layout
 *
 * @param error error text
 */
@Override
public void setError(@Nullable CharSequence error) {
    if (error == null) {
        setHint(originalHint);
        setHintTextAppearance(R.style.InputLayoutNormalHint);
        setUnderlineColor(R.color.input_normal_accent);
    } else {
        setHint(error);
        setHintTextAppearance(R.style.InputLayoutErrorHint);
        setUnderlineColor(R.color.input_error_accent);
    }
}

/**
 * colorized layout specified green color
 *
 * @param acceptedHint text for floating label
 */
public void setGreenError(@NonNull CharSequence acceptedHint) {
    setHint(acceptedHint);
    setHintTextAppearance(R.style.InputLayoutAcceptedHint);
    setUnderlineColor(R.color.input_accepted_accent);
}

private void setUnderlineColor(@ColorRes int colorRes) {
    if (getEditText() != null) {
        getEditText().getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), colorRes), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }
}
}
```

style

```
<style name="InputLayoutErrorHint" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/input_error_accent</item>
</style>

<style name="InputLayoutNormalHint" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/input_normal_accent</item>
</style>

<style name="InputLayoutAcceptedHint" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/input_accepted_accent</item>
</style>
```