# How to change error background of TextInputLayoutText error when using a border?

Tags: android

I'm using Android Design Library's TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText with a background. When setting an error, the field is highlighted with a rather jarring red background that my client dislikes.

I *can* style away the red background if I don't include the field border, but not if I use one. I've tried all the styling options that I've seen in the relevant S/O answers with no success.

I also tried setting the background in code after setting the error as described in the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722034/how-to-change-color-of-textinputlayouts-label-and-edittext-underline-android), and the red background *is* temporarily removed from the input field, but reappears as soon as the field is reentered. I tried adding a focus change listener and redoing the setBackgroundResource call, but I still get the red background. Stepping through with a debugger shows that there is a frame choreographer message posted that eventually adds the background color back. Since this approach always felt like a work-around, I haven't tried to post my own messages to set it back.

It appears to me that my desired background resource is being replaced by a background color one. Is there a way to style that away that I'm just not seeing?
[image]
[image]

Comment: have you solve this issue ?

Comment: No, since I needed it for some immediate client work, I just implemented the desired parts of functionality manually.

Answer (score 1):

i've managed to do it by putting transparent background like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:top="5dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="13dp"
                android:left="13dp"
                android:right="13dp"
                android:top="13dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```