# How to create such bottom border highlight for EditText without using Google's material library?

Tags: android, material-design

I discovered for myself Google's material design, but I can't use their library for some reasons, but I want to implement such bottom border highlight.
[Desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kyJs.png)

Do I need to create a custom view for this or maybe use some library? It'll be great if a solution will support API >=19 but any help appreciated.

Thanks for attention!

Comment: Refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722034/how-to-change-color-of-textinputlayouts-label-and-edittext-underline-android

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the part of your question where you indicate "but I can't use their library for some reason" I have a potential solution for that. You can add the material design dependency using the Project Structure or directly to Gradle in Android Studio.

Project Structure:
File > Project Structure > app > Dependencies > "+" sign > Library dependency > search for "design" > select option "com.android.support:design:27.1.1" (or whichever version aligns with your system.

Gradle:
In build.gradle (Module: app) add `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'` in your dependencies.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```