# How to change the background stroke color in TextInputLayout in android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I am using the InputTextLayout in xml design. I want to change the stroke color. How can i achieve this?

Comment: will you want to change the border color of the textinput layout?

Comment: If you mean bottom line color, it's accent color of your theme. Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31723120/244611

Answer (score 0):

Use the **`app:boxStrokeColor`** attribute

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      app:boxStrokeColor="@color/...."
      ...>
```

You can use a color or a selector.