# Color controls not working for TextInputLayout in com.google.android.material:material versions ABOVE 1.0.0

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

Color control is not working in color controls not working for TextInputLayout in com.google.android.material:material versions ABOVE 1.0.0.

I have this in my `styles.xml`:

```xml
<style name="BaseTextField">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/pink</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/alabaster</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/pink</item>
</style>
```

And in my layout:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    ...
    ...
    android:theme="@style/BaseTextField"/>
```

It was working perfectly on version 1.0.0. But when upgrading to higher versions. The control controls doesn't work anymore. Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: what do you want to change?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti The underline color and the floating label color. Currently, it resorts to using the app theme's `colorPrimary`.

Comment: You can check these questions: [how to change color of TextinputLayout's label and edittext underline android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57985955/2016562) and [How to change the floating label color of TextInputLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57811487/2016562)