# how to remove ripple effect on edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

[image: gif]

when I touched the somewhere on the screen , edittext text color changed I used AppCompatEditText inside TextInputLayout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change color of TextinputLayout's label and edittext underline android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722034/how-to-change-color-of-textinputlayouts-label-and-edittext-underline-android)

Comment: @ADM unfortunately not

Comment: Add the layout with question .