# Why won't my textinputlayout be the correct color when pressed?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following code in my themes.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Something" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2D77B6</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#2D77B6</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">#2D77B6</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">#2D77B6</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#2D77B6</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorOnSurface">#2D77B6</item>
</style>
```

Because I want the color of #2D77B6 to be everywhere. I then have an textinputlayout like the following:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userNameInputLayout"
        android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:backgroundTint="#2D77B6"
        android:textColorHint="#3281C5"
        android:textColor="#2D77B6"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:textColorHint="#3281C5"
            android:textColor="#2D77B6"
            android:backgroundTint="#2D77B6"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

However, when I press the TextInputLayout for entering my username my floating text along with the underline becomes dark green. How can I change this?

Comment: There are a lot of issues. First of all you have to use a MaterialComponentsTheme.Then use `boxBackgroundColor` instead of `backgroundTint`, then check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722034/how-to-change-color-of-textinputlayouts-label-and-edittext-underline-android/57985955#57985955

Comment: Thank you. The line "<item name="colorControlActivated">#2D77B6</item>" solved the issue in the themes.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Gabriele who commented before. This question is now closed. The solution was to add the following line in the themes.xml file:

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">#2D77B6</item>
```