# Change thickness of the bottom line of EditText when wrapped into TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, styles, material-design, android-textinputlayout

here is my code

**XML Markup**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etContactName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Contact Name"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Style**

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hintColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/hintColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primaryColor</item>
</style>
```

**Here is the output**
(normal view)
[image: Normal View]

(focused view)

[image: Focused View]

**Now My Problems / Issues**

1. I want the bottom line to be thinner. where should I change it.
2. The blinking cursor is not showing, how to show it.
3. EditText is automatically highlighting the spelling mistakes. I need to stop it.

Can anyone please point me to the right way to resolve the issues. Comment you anyone needs more info to answer this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you resolve this? Could you share with us?

Comment: @Selin: Posted my solution

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I've solved my issue using my custom xml drawable. There might be some better way, but I couldn't find any. following is my drawable that I'm using as background of my textbox

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list >
            <item
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="-2dp"
                android:right="-2dp"
                android:top="-2dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <stroke
                        android:width="0.5dp"
                        android:color="@color/primaryColor" />

                    <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />

                    <padding android:left="3dp"
                        android:right="3dp"
                        android:top="3dp"
                        android:bottom="3dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>

        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <layer-list >
            <item
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="-2dp"
                android:right="-2dp"
                android:top="-2dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <stroke
                        android:width="0.5dp"
                        android:color="@color/primaryColor" />

                    <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />

                    <padding android:left="3dp"
                        android:right="3dp"
                        android:top="3dp"
                        android:bottom="3dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>

        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list >
            <item
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="-2dp"
                android:right="-2dp"
                android:top="-2dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <stroke
                        android:width="0.5dp"
                        android:color="#BCBCBC" />

                    <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />

                    <padding android:left="3dp"
                        android:right="3dp"
                        android:top="3dp"
                        android:bottom="3dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>

        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Finally, thanks. This worked for me, after trying like 20 different things mentioned in other posts

Comment: Thanks a ton sir. Tried a lot of things but this worked out at the end.

Comment: I've tried about 7 different options and this is literally the only one that works as expected in every single scenario.

Comment: Great! Worked for me!

Comment: This works. But there is a strange padding between line and text that I cant remove

Answer (score 0):

Edittext bottom color

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/yourcolor"
```

To disable spellchecker  add code in your Edittext xml

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Create an XML file with the name "EditTextStyle.xml" in the drawable folder in your project and write the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/r..."
   android:thickness="0dp"
   android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="3dp"
     android:color="#4799E8"/>
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
  <gradient
  android:startColor="#C8C8C8"
  android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
  android:type="linear"
  android:angle="270"/>
  </shape>
```

Now add the following attribute to your EditText:

```
       <EditText    

        android:background="@drawable/EditTextStyle"/>
```

Comment: I'm able to change EditText bottom color, I need to change stroke width thinner.

Comment: Didn't work , need line but it create rectangle