# Change Edittext line color when on focus

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext

I've been trying to change the baseline color for my edittext when on focus but it doesn't seem to work..

Here's my .xml snippet:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_passwordWrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_10"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_10"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_10"
                android:hint="@string/hint_login_password"
               >
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="#000000"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    app:backgroundTint="#000000"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And here is my styles-v21 file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@android:transition/slide_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@android:transition/slide_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
```

where : 
- ColorPrimary = #CD060C (red)
- ColorPrimaryDark = #8B181B (darker-red)

I tested this on a Lollipop device and it works great. I can't say the same for my Marshamallow device. I took a look at the issue here on S.O to see how this can be solved for M and above devices. Someone suggested an approach which consist of adding these few lines of code in my activity class:

```
passwordWrapper.getEditText().setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){
            if (hasFocus)
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                    v.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorBlackTransparent)));
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

On my Marshmallow device, whenever I focus on the edittext, I keep on having the coloraccent i.e red color for the baseline..I want it to be black..

Does anyone has a workaround on this issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First of all you don't need to use a `setOnFocusChangeListener` to change underline color of `TextInputLayout`

There is android item attribute for that, which will change color when your `edittext` is activated.

Add this attribute in you base theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#000000</item>  //black color
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#000000</item>
</style>
```

make sure you use the theme in activity: Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base"/>
```

**EDIT**

setting `colorControlHighlight` will affect the navigation drawer selected item color. so use:

in res/drawable/drawer.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

now in your navigation view set the background as:

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer"
```

Comment: Yeah I know about using colorControlHighlight and  colorControlActivated (I've already tried it actually...). However,  I have a nav drawer in my app and changing the default colorControlHighlight to black will affect my nav drawer highlight color. That's why I have been looking for a way around in the activity class directly..

Comment: I tried your proposal......and i'm still stuck with the red color (on marshamallow..) when the edittext is activated

Comment: Focused edit text still had color primary color for me, so I had to use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36543554/2413303