# Change color bottom line of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles, android-design-library

I have a `EditText` in `TextInputLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputTextUser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/user_hint"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I want change bottom line color to white, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546430/how-to-change-the-floating-label-color-of-textinputlayout/30914037#30914037) solution, but It's not work with me:

```
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_blue_A400</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
```

Here is image after style theme:

[image]
[image]

Is there any suggestion to change color bottom line when un-focus and focus?

Comment: I think it's the colorAccent color you set in the styles.

Comment: The color I set is `Pink` color

Comment: Just Go to Your color.xml file and change the <color name="colorAccent">#00FF00</color> to your needed color. i.e. to #FFFFFF for white.

Comment: The colorAccent is `Pink` color. You can see the bottom line is black color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this :

```
mEditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(YOUR_COLOR_HERE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

eg :

```
mEditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
```

Comment: Can I do this by style or xml?

Comment: have a look at this answer on stackoverflow - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24879187/3026884)

Comment: I see this answer on stackoverflow but It's not work with me.

Comment: @AkashSingh... You saved my day & time . +1 vote for u. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `java code` and using `styles` you can change this `color`:-

use this on your

```
EditTextmUserName.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourWhiteColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

and using styles:- use `appcompat` theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>

    </style>
```

change your `colorAccent` to white

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/whiteColor</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple style here http://android-holo-colors.com/ this will generate the images need with the different color and the style.xml with the correct attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The **backgroundTint** attribute is responsible for the color of the bottom line.

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/yourColor"
```

To remove the bottom line, use a transparent color

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
```