# How to add underline for EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to customize the underline of `EditText` as shown below?

[image]

Comment: Picture could have been a bit smaller

Comment: Create a Drawable in XML and set as background of EditText.

Comment: Please google it before posting question.There are plenty of examples available.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480398/edittext-underline-below-text-property

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editRemarks"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addNoteRemarks"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_shape"/>
```

and below is the drawable file  "edit_text_shape"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <!-- Draw a 2dp width border around shape -->
        <stroke
            android:color="@color/viewfinder_laser"
            android:width="2dp"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- Overlap the left, top and right border using background color  -->
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```