# (Material) EditText underline color

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles

My problem is that I don't know how to change underline color of EditText - I have LG Nexus 5 (**Android 6**).

[image]

I would like to change normal **underline color** to **white**. I used all **params** like (style):

- colorControlNormal
- colorControlActivated
- colorControlHighlight
- textColorSecondary
- colorPrimary
- colorPrimaryDark

e.g.

```
<style name="FormFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/form_text_size</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
</style>
```

but nothing seems to work (it only changes color when EditText us focused like in above pic).

Comment: I could help you better if you put snippets of the XML layout and styles used.

Comment: I updated my post however its nothing advanced

Comment: I've found an answer from another question.Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7) for the answer.

Comment: I checked it - it's silly it works only when set in main AppTheme but not when set in different style like I did. What if I don't want to use the same color in every EditText of my app ?

Comment: Did your problem was solved?

Comment: By default it take <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/white</item> for widgets color

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I checked it - it's silly it works only when set in main AppTheme but not when set in different style like I did. What if I don't want to use the same color in every EditText of my app ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible. I'll check it and make you know if I find something.

Comment: You can make a separate style for your EditTexts and set the parent of that to `Theme.App.Base` and apply that to the EditTexts of your choice via `android:theme="@style/Theme.App.YourEditTextTheme"` in your XML layout

Comment: I think that your Theme must be a child of Theme.AppCompat.*

Comment: I found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584882/how-to-change-focus-color-of-edittext-in-android/4585750#4585750). 

Basically what it says is you're going to create your background by using a NinePatch Image(you can create by using [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) one by Roman Nurik itself) and than build it as your new StateListDrawable.

Comment: I wanted to avoid NinePatch but it might be the only answer

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient thing to do is to add the colorAccent attribute in your AppTheme style like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">         

<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>    
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText"/>
```

The colorAccent attribute is used for widget tinting throughout the app and thus should be used for consistency

Comment: But I want only these edit texts to change. Color accent has broader impact

Answer (score 1):

Try using `android:backgroundTint="#yourUnderlineColor"`.

> Only available for API 21 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

> To make it work in **Android 6**, create your custom theme in
>   `res/values-v21/styles.xml` .

```
<style name="FormFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
</style>
<style name="FormFontWhite" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

and apply then in your `EditText`

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/FormFont"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/FormFontWhite"/>
```

For more info check [@reVerse answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30150754/4848308) .

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/cux_label_password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    app:theme="@style/editTextStyle" />
```

```
  <style name="editTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FFFFFF</item>

    </style>
```