# Change Edit Text Underline Color to be the same when off focused & focused

Tags: android, xml

[image]My Edit Text underline seems to always be highlighted when focused, I've been trying to have all lines the same color as the first one in the picture, here is my XML code, would anyone know how to have all three lines highlighted (even when other edit text's are not focused)? Thanks in advance!!!

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_password_second"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@color/edit_text_color"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/edit_text_color"
```

Comment: The color of the underline is currently the same. The thing that changes is line thickness, which makes it look like a difference. In addition, it is actually slightly darker

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try adding a theme

```
<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

and set it on your EditText

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme">
</EditText>
```

Comment: Hey Stamatis, thanks for your help, I've tried this, although it adds a typing line and remove the hooks at the end of each line, which is not a big deal, but i would like to keep them. Would you happen to know a way around this?

Comment: check that answer. I haven't tried it but i think you should.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4585750/6792992

Answer (score 2):

Go to `styles.xml` and change `<item name="colorAccent">#YOUR_COLOR</item>` to the same color as your EditText's backgroundTint

Comment: Thanks for your time grant, I've tried your suggestion, even after adding colorAccent, the unfocused edit texts are still the same darker colors