# Changing Text Hint style in Text Input Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to change the hint text style to capital when edit text is focussed. When not focussed keep it normal. Using xml only

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyFilledBox"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:hint="test app"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
    app:endIconTint="@color/black">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "setOnFocusChangeListener" method for our EditText

```
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                mInputLayout.setHint("un capitalize hint"")
            }else {
                mInputLayout.setHint("CAPITALIZE HINT"")
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: I need to handle it using style or using the xml only

Comment: I don't think you can change text syle using the style way. Only background can be edited. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584882/how-to-change-focus-color-of-edittext-in-android#answer-4585750